# How to calculate the volume integral of $f(x,y,z)=\cos(x)$ on $D = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <1\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

> Calculate $\displaystyle\iiint_Df(x,y,z)\, dx\,dy\,dz$ with $f(x,y,z) = \cos(x)$ and $D = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1 \}.$

I struggle to do this as there are three coefficients to use. If we had only $x^2 + y^2 <1$ then I would just put $x \in (-1,1)$ and $-\sqrt{1-x^2}<y < + \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and then would simply calculate 
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \left( \int _{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cos(x)\,dy \right) dx$$

But here I get one additional term $z$, and I am unsure of how to proceed.

I believe that I might try to do this:

$x \in (-1,1)$, $-\sqrt{1-x^2}<y^2 + z^2 <\sqrt{1-x^2} $ thus we would have $-\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x^2}-y^2}<z<\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x^2}-y^2}$. And then:

$$\iiint_Df(x,y,z) \,dx\,dy\,dz = \int_{-1}^{1}\cos(x) \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \left( \int_{-\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x^2}-y^2}}^{\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x^2}-y^2}} 1\,dz \right)dy \,dx $$

Which equates to:

$$ \int_{-1}^{1}\cos(x) 2\int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}} \sqrt{\sqrt{1-x^2}-y^2}\, dx\,dy.$$

Which I believe will give me rather tedious calculations to do, so before proceeding, I wish to know if I am on the right track?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe spherical coordinates could help since $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: In spherical coordinates, the integral is just as bad: $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^1\cos(r\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi))\,r^2\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\varphi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed $x_0\in[-1,1]$, the area of $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1, x=x_0\}$ is given by $\pi(1-x_0^2)$, hence the given integral is equivalent to
$$ \pi\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x_0)^2 \cos(x_0)\,dx_0$$
or to $\color{red}{4\pi\cos(1)}$, by integration by parts.